# Code coverage lines inside subscribe method in Angular 7

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, code-coverage, istanbul

I have the following code and cannot test the lines in red, using Istanbul:

[image: Istanbul code coverage snippet]

The test is the following, but no error is detected:

```
it('should set user info JSON to local storage after successful authentication', async(() => {
    component.loginForm.get('username').setValue('test');
    component.loginForm.get('passwd').setValue('test');

    spyOn(loginService, 'postLogin').and.returnValues(of({}));

    component.sendLoginForm();

    expect(component.loginFormSuccess).toEqual(true);
    expect(component.loginFormFail).toEqual(false);

    component.loggedInUserJSON = '{"login":"test","password":"test"}';
    localStorage.setItem('loggedInUserJSON', component.loggedInUserJSON);
    fakeLocalStorage.setItem('loggedInUserJSON', component.loggedInUserJSON);

    expect(localStorage.getItem('loggedInUserJSON')).toBe(component.loggedInUserJSON);
    expect(fakeLocalStorage.getItem('loggedInUserJSON')).toBe(component.loggedInUserJSON);

    expect(component.loggedInUserJSON).toBe('{"login":"test","password":"test"}');

    expect(component.postLoginObservable).toBeTruthy();
}));
```

Comment: Please look at my answer.

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you spy on the service, return the below as inside the subscribe, it is looking for it:

```
 spyOn(loginService, 'postLogin').and.returnValues(of({
  result : {
     httpStatus : 200
  }
}));
```

So, when it performs the test, it will look for the condition `(response.result.httpStatus === 200)` which evalutes to **true**

Similarly, in another test, add the httpStatus as 400 so that it executes the other
condition and spy on the method `showInvalidAuthentication` an expect it to be called.

**To check the routing part,**

```
let routerStub = { navigate: jasmine.createSpy('navigate') };
```

And add it in the providers:

```
providers: [{ provide: Router, useValue: routerStub }]
```

In the test, when the `httpStatus` is `200`, expect the below

```
 expect(routerStub.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/home']);
```

With the above, your tests will cover lines `110 & 113`